# How i can implement a BackgroundWorker in C++ STL

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

Hello i'm newbie in C++ specially on STL,

I need to create a function with an infinite loop to calculate and process big data (such as Genetic Algorithm), but i also need **keep Ui responsive** and update it within (after each round) that infinite loop and start/stop operation manually.

something like this:

```
bool working = false;
void do_process()
{
    while(working)
    {
       // do some stuff
    }
}

void btnStart()
{
    working = true; 
    do_process();
}

void btnEnd()
{
    working = false;
}
```

would you please guide me to a proper solution without any 3rdparty lib, thanks.

and apologies for terrible English.

Comment: If you want to keep pressing the button to queue up more `do_process` jobs, take a look at `std::vector` to store additional `std::thread`s as required ... Buuuuut...  that's often a bad idea as too many threads start fighting over access to the CPU and other resources. It's also a pain to have to maintain the `vector` and clean up after expired threads. Instead [look into thread pools](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173575/what-is-a-thread-pool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should get you started. But be careful, implementing a multi-threading application is generally a hard problem also for experienced users. Lot of knowledge is required about memory access synchronization and deadlock analysis. Consider the example below is really essential. For instance, in btnStart and btnStop you should check if a thread is already running. Checking the global bool `working` may require synchronization. Similarly, checking for null pointer may require synchronization. Bottom line, it is way more complicate than it may seem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>

bool working = false;
std::unique_ptr<std::thread> t;

void do_process()
{
    while(working)
    {
        std::cout << "Hi. I am a secondary thread and I am running.\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}

void btnStart()
{
    working = true;
    t.reset(new std::thread(do_process)); // start the thread
}

void btnEnd()
{
    working = false;  // inform the thread of termination
    t->join();        // wait for thread termination
    t.reset(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hi, I am the main thread.\n";
    std::cout << "I'll now launch another thread and sleep for a while\n";
    btnStart();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
    btnEnd();
    std::cout << "What happened while I was slepping?\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pretty good answer, but there is [no need for the `std::unique_ptr`](https://ideone.com/59mVWD) here and I'd go the extra step and demonstrate `std::atomic` for `working`. Armoring `btnStart` so that no one smashes the current running thread I'd leave to another question.

Comment: solved; my problem was about unique_ptr, thanks, unfortunately i have not enough reputation to give you score-;)

Comment: @user4581301  i couldn't (shouldn't) use std::atomic

Comment: @Hamed puzzled. Could I ask why not? It is a very simple (because it hides a lot of truly nasty stuff) solution to an otherwise thorny problem.

Comment: @user4581301 some sort of company rules, this algorithm must works on portable devices not pc or mac.

Comment: You have a race condition.